# How do you check if a char is a number in c?

Tags: c, char, atof

I'm using `atof(word)`, where word is a `char` type. It works when the word is a number, such as 3 or 2, but atof doesn't distinguish when word is an operator, such as `"+"`. Is there a better way to check whether the char is a number?

I'm a newbie to CS, so I'm quite confused on how to do this properly.

Comment: `atof()` doesn't take a `char` type it takes a `char` pointer to a string, i.e. a *null* terminated sequence of bytes.

Comment: Are you checking a single `char` like `'7'` or an string like `"1234"`?

Comment: I have a text file that has numbers in it, they could be single or multiple digits, I'm reading the words one by one and checking to see if the word is a number

Answer (score 5):

If you're checking a single `char`, use the `isdigit` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    printf("2 is digit: %s\n", isdigit('2') ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("+ is digit: %s\n", isdigit('+') ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("a is digit: %s\n", isdigit('a') ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Output:

```
2 is digit: yes
+ is digit: no
a is digit: no
```

Comment: Ho did you exactly got [2 is digit: 1](http://ideone.com/I2uHfQ)?

Comment: @Michi Rewrote the output to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, `strtol()`. Example

```
char *endptr;
const char *input = "32xaxax";
int value = strtol(input, &endptr, 10);
if (*endptr != '\0')
    fprintf(stderr, "`%s' are not numbers\n");
```

The above would print `"`xaxax' are not numbers"`.

The idea is that this function stops when it finds any non numeric character, and makes `endptr` point to the place where the non numeric character appeared in the original pointer. This will not consider and "*operator*" as a non numeric value because `"+10"` is convertible to `10` since the sign is used as the sign of the number, if you want to parse the "*operator*" between two operands you need a parser, a simple one could be written using `strpbrk(input, "+-*/")`, read the manual for `strpbrk()`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean if a string contains only digits?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "241";
    char *ptr = str;

    while (isdigit(*ptr)) ptr++;
    printf("str is %s number\n", (ptr > str) && (*str == 0) ? "a" : "not a");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by word, you mean a string, which in C, is either a char* or a char[].

Personally I would use `atoi()`

```
This function returns the converted integral number as an int value. If no valid conversion could be performed, it returns zero.
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void is_number(char*);

int main(void) {
    char* test1 = "12";
    char* test2 = "I'm not a number";

    is_number(test1);
    is_number(test2);
    return 0;
}

void is_number(char* input){
    if (atoi(input)!=0){
        printf("%s: is a number\n", input);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s: is not a number\n", input);
    }
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
12: is a number
I'm not a number: is not a number
```

However if you're just checking a single character, then just use isdigit()